# Installing gfortran using MSYS2

Tags: installation, compilation, fortran, gfortran, msys2

As a complete beginner, I am struggling to install gfortran using MSYS2. My end-goal is to compile multiple '.for' files and create an executable. As a first try, I am trying to create an executable for a simple Fortran code.

The steps I have taken are as following:

1. I have downloaded the 'MSYS2 installer-64 bit' from https://www.msys2.org/
2. Once the download is finished, I have started the installer and accepted the default options.
3. Installer suggested to run **MSYS2 64bit** and I accepted.
4. I tried updating using the command `pacman -Syu`
5. I got a permission error since my user account on my work computer does not have administrative privileges. I am able to run programs using the administrator password (Right click - run as administrator). However I need the compiler to work also when to log in to my user account (without administrative privileges). I might need some help to set things up properly.

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed to update mingw32 (unable to lock database)
error: failed to update mingw64 (unable to lock database)
error: failed to update ucrt64 (unable to lock database)
error: failed to update clang64 (unable to lock database)
error: failed to update msys (unable to lock database)
error: failed to synchronize all databases
```

6. I tried running **MSYS2 64bit** as an administrator and repeated the update procedure using the command `pacman -Syu`. This time everything went OK.

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 mingw32 is up to date   0.0   B  0.00   B/s 00:00 [---------------------]   0%
 mingw64 is up to date   0.0   B  0.00   B/s 00:00 [---------------------]   0%
 ucrt64 is up to date    0.0   B  0.00   B/s 00:00 [---------------------]   0%
 clang64 is up to date   0.0   B  0.00   B/s 00:00 [---------------------]   0%
 msys is up to date      0.0   B  0.00   B/s 00:00 [---------------------]   0%
:: Starting core system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
:: Starting full system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
```

7. Using Notepad, I create a file named **hello.for** in the directory "c/Users/User1/Desktop/CompileTry":

```
         program HelloWorld
           write (*,*) 'Hello, world'
         end program HelloWorld
```

8. While running **MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit** as an administrator, I change the directory to the working directory using the command `cd /c/Users/User1/Desktop/CompileTry`
9. I try to create an executable using the command `gfortran hello.for -o hello`
10. This is the error output I get:

```
# gfortran hello.for -o hello
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libm.a when searching for -lm
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libm.a when searching for -lm
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `_signal'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `_signal'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `_signal'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `__fpreset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0xf0): undefined reference to `_signal'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `_signal'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `_signal'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `_SetUnhandledExceptionFilter@4'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x167): undefined reference to `___cpu_features_init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `__fpreset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `__CRT_glob'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x19f): undefined reference to `___getmainargs'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1a4): undefined reference to `__CRT_fmode'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1ad): undefined reference to `__fmode'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1b3): undefined reference to `__imp___iob'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1c5): undefined reference to `__CRT_fmode'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1ce): undefined reference to `__imp___iob'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1d9): undefined reference to `__setmode'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1df): undefined reference to `__imp___iob'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to `__CRT_fmode'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1f2): undefined reference to `__imp___iob'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x1fd): undefined reference to `__setmode'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x211): undefined reference to `___p__fmode'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x217): undefined reference to `__fmode'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x21e): undefined reference to `__pei386_runtime_relocator'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x226): undefined reference to `___main'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x22b): undefined reference to `___p__environ'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x247): undefined reference to `_main'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `__cexit'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x256): undefined reference to `_ExitProcess@4'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x265): undefined reference to `__imp___iob'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x270): undefined reference to `__setmode'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x276): undefined reference to `__imp___iob'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x28f): undefined reference to `__imp____set_app_type'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x2af): undefined reference to `__imp____set_app_type'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference to `__imp__atexit'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95/Lib/../lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x2d3): undefined reference to `__imp___onexit'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ertr000001.o:(.rdata+0x0): undefined reference to `_pei386_runtime_relocator'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

11. There is no executable file created in the folder and this is the only error message.

Can anyone please help me in resolving this problem?

Edit:

Output for the command `printenv`:

```
.installerid=EA11LCT
.osfamily=10
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
.installserver=rollout
.termserver=no
.source=\\rollout\master\rollout\sysadmin\EA11LCT
.rolloutpe=yes
.temp=C:\temp
.id2=EA11LCT ANSYS Chemkin 17.0 - v15.64.15151 [EA11LCT]
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
.jumpto=aEA11LCT_Chemkin17
.group=ea11.lct.wp
.id1=EA11LCT_Chemkin17
!C:=C:\Windows\System32
.oslanguage=en
.IsLaptop=yes
.osid=10E1709E64
.installdate=12.04.2018
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
WD=C:\msys64\usr\bin\
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.5.0
MINGW_PREFIX=/mingw64
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
HOSTNAME=ea11c317
PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files
MSYSTEM=MINGW64
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
ORIGINAL_TEMP=/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp
MINGW_CHOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32
OS=Windows_NT
UATDATA=C:\Windows\CCM\UATData\D9F8C395-CAB8-491d-B8AC-179A1FE1BE77
INTEL_DEV_REDIST=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\
MSYSTEM_CARCH=x86_64
USERDOMAIN=EA11C317
PWD=/home/Administrator
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Administrator
IFORT_COMPILER15=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2015\
IFORT_COMPILER11=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Compiler\11.1\072\
MANPATH=/mingw64/local/man:/mingw64/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man:/share/man
PRINTER=PDFCreator
JD2_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\JDownloader 2.0
VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\
TZ=Europe/Brussels
LOG=C:\DICT\logs\dict.log
MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX=mingw-w64-x86_64
tmp=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
ORIGINAL_PATH=/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
HOME=/home/Administrator
USERNAME=Administrator
VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
OneDrive=C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive
COMSPEC=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
VTUNE_AMPLIFIER_2019_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\VTune Amplifier 2019\
RoxioCentral=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\Roxio Central36\
VSSHELL2008INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
APPDATA=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming
SYSTEMROOT=C:\WINDOWS
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local
PROMPT=$P$G
COMPUTERNAME=EA11C317
INFOPATH=/usr/local/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/info:/share/info
TERM=xterm
ACLOCAL_PATH=/mingw64/share/aclocal:/usr/share/aclocal
USER=EA11C317+Administrator
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Athena\g95\Lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Athena\g95\lib\gcc-lib\i686-pc-mingw32\4.0.4
TEMP=/tmp
temp=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp
MSYSTEM_CHOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32
ORIGINAL_TMP=/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp
SHLVL=1
PROCESSOR_REVISION=8e0a
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CONICON=mingw64.ico
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
PS1=\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[35m\]$MSYSTEM\[\e[0m\] \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\[\e[1m\]#\[\e[0m\]
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/mingw64/share/:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
MSYSCON=mintty.exe
TMP=/tmp
CONFIG_SITE=/etc/config.site
PATH=/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
MSYSTEM_PREFIX=/mingw64
LOGINSHELL=bash
CONTITLE=MinGW x64
MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\compiler\lib\mic
INTEL_LICENSE_FILE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Licenses
WINDIR=C:\WINDOWS
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Athena\Lib
SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
OLDPWD=/c/WINDOWS/system32
TERM_PROGRAM=mintty
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Comment: Is that `C:/Program Files (x86)/Athena/g95` somehow in the PATH? If it is, you need to remove it from there.

Comment: Can you please help me understand what you mean by the PATH? How can I change the options regarding PATH? I would really appreciate any kind of source that explains the procedure.

Comment: I mean the environment variable. Do `echo $PATH` from MSYS2 to see the contents. If you didn't touch it, then that folder shouldn't be there, but who knows.

Comment: The command `echo $PATH` yields the following output:
`/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl`. The above mentioned folder does not seem to be in the list.

Comment: Weird. Can you please post the output of `which gfortran`, and also check if this folder is mentioned in the output of `printenv`?

Comment: Output for the command `which gfortran`:
```/mingw64/bin/gfortran```

Comment: Okay, what about `printenv`? I'm not sure what prompts your compiler to even look in that directory.

Comment: I have added the output of the command `printenv` in the original question since the output was quite large. There seems to be a mention of that folder in a variable called `LIBRARY_PATH`. This folder belongs to a specific software called Athena Studio. Do you know how can I remove this relationship in GFortran? Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: The variables `LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIB` mention that directory. I'd undefine them temporarily (using `unset LIBRARY_PATH`, `unset LIB` in MSYS2) and try again. This only affects MSYS2 (and only until its restarted), not the actual variables.

Comment: I used the commands `unset LIBRARY_PATH` and `unset LIB` in MSYS2. Then I tried compiling again and finally an executable was formed. However, when I try to run the executable, I get the following error: "The code execution cannot proceed because msys-gfortran-5.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem." Would you have any ideas what might be the cause?

Comment: Do you have this file somewhere in MSYS2 installation?

Comment: Yes, this file is located in the folder `C:\msys64\usr\bin`. I realize that Windows cannot find this file. When I try to run the executable in 'MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit', it successfully executes. Would you know how can I make windows recognize this folder?

Comment: Something is wrong with your compiler installation. You want to have `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran` package, not `gcc-fortran`. In general, you don't want any compilers or libraries not prefixed with `mingw-w64-x86_64-`.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. I have only followed the steps that I have described in the question. Would you recommend me to change something in the procedure? Or would you have any other recommendations?

Comment: You didn't explain how you installed the fortran compiler from MSYS2. Did you do it at all?

Comment: You are right, I must have forgot to mention it. I installed it in MSYS2 using the command `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`.

Comment: Did you install any other packages?

Comment: I was only trying to install gfortran so I did not install any other packages. Is there any way to check this or what went wrong during installation?

Comment: Try reinstalling MSYS2 from scratch, just in case.

Comment: Would you have any recommendations for changing the steps I took during the installation procedure?

Comment: No, the steps seem fine. I'm worried that you installed some extra packages in addition to `mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the replies. You have been extremely helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same situations with the reinstall. I still have to run MSYS2 as an administrator and I need to use the commands `unset LIBRARY_PATH` and `unset LIB` in MSYS2 in the beginning. The executable only works when I try to run it in 'MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit', but not directly from Windows explorer.

Comment: MSYS2 provides at least two different toolchains: the one from `mingw-w64-x86_64-...` packages and the one from unprefixed packages (e.g. `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` vs `gcc`). You normally want the former, but that dll belongs to the latter. When I compile a fortran 'hello world' with the former, it doesn't depend on that dll. Usually, launching MSYS2 using `mingw64.exe`, installing packages prefixed with `mingw-w64-x86_64-` (instead of unprefixed) should be enough, so I'm not sure what's going on on your side.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation. I might have got mixed up with the subtle difference in the package names, I will double check again.

Comment: I retried the reinstallation process. I made sure I only installed the correct package with the command `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`. Unfortunately nothing changed. I still have to run MSYS2 as an administrator, I need to use the commands `unset LIBRARY_PATH` and `unset LIB` in MSYS2 in the beginning. The created executable still gives the .dll errors when run directly from Windows explorer. When I copy/paste the executable in the folder "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin", where the dlls are located, it runs fine. Do you know how can I make sure Windows knows where the dlls are located?

Comment: Either add the directory with dlls to PATH in Windows settings, or copy the dlls next to the exe.

Comment: Adding the directory to PATH in Windows settings did not work for me, but I was able to copy the dlls next to the executable and make it work. Thank you very much for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Installing Fortran on my new DELL with Windows I had similar problems.  It was 3 years since I installed MSYS2 and Fortran on my current PC so I had forgotten how I did it.

Starting by installing msys2 following the instructions on the MSYS2 page at github I created a directory c:\msys64\ with an executable mingw64.exe (and
I made a shortcut to this on the desktop as I had on my old PC).

But trying to find which package contained the Fortran compiler I was lost. There were packages such as mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libgfortran but adding this with pacman -S ...  included only lib files. I used pacman -Q to list packages but no package "mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran" (as proposed by @HolyBlackCat in a comment) was listed.

But following this suggestion I tested:
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran
and that worked!

I appreciate the hard work of those developing and updating the msys2 package and I also appreciate the help from stack overflow to find this package.  But it could maybe be made a bit easier to find things.

I notice that after installing the package mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran
this package is listed when I try pacman -Q
maybe some bug in pacman?

Bo Sundman